# Access port behing carrier grade NAT

Tags: networking, router

I am trying to send data through MQTT between two Raspberry Pi's over LTE. Raspberry Pi's are connected to internet via Huawei USB surfstick. when i checked on port open utilities online, it seems port1883 is open. Yet I am not able to publish data. I think I am behind carrier grad NAT so not able to send data to ports or  my ISP is blocking incoming traffic at ports. How can i achieve this ? Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work out if you are behind CGNAT, check your machine's IP address with ifconfig. If it's an [RFC 1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) number, then you are. If it is not an RFC 1918 number, you might still be. Check your public IP address via [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/), if it doesn't match the output of ifconfig, then you are.

If one or both devices are behind a CGNAT implementation, the only way to connect into an open port would be to have an intermediate device sitting between them negotiating connections. For example, a VPN server that both Pis can connect into, thus creating an end-to-end VPN tunnel between them.

Comment: yes i thought this as an option. How can i find from ifconfig result if I am behind CGNAT or not ?

Comment: @Spark, added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Under ppp0 interface in ifconfig result, I get a public IP address and when I cross checked using whatismyip website it gives me back the same IP address. so does that mean I am not behind CGNAT?

Comment: @Spark. Yes, it would appear you are not behind CGNAT.

Comment: But still I am not able to send data to 1883 port. what might be the reason ?

Comment: @Spark. Could be the port/protocol is blocked. Could be the MQTT server is not correctly configured and listening. Could be blocked by a firewall (iptables). Could be anything really... I suggest you start a new question (as this one was about CGNAT - feel free to accept the answer BTW) and dump as much information about your setup and config files as possible. Judicious use of Wireshark/tcpdump would be the first thing I try in these situations.