# How do i Setup port forwarding for the Genexis Titanium- 2122A

Tags: port-forwarding

I wanted to host a minecraft server on my pc but I cant open the port 25565.
I Have tried lots of tutorials and solutions from websites but none seem to work for me.
[router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evKcs.png)
[port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FujmY.png)
My public ip shows like this 103.XX.XX.X

Comment: When you attempt to determine your public IP address, what is the beginning value of the subnet, please provide this information has an [edit] to your question. I have a suspicion that you are behind a carrier NAT. What you have done should be enough, if it's not working, then it's likely due to your ISP. To be clear I am asking for a single value, from your IP address `XXX.YYY.ZZZ.VVV`, I want to know the value of `XXX`. [Information Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1254850/access-port-behing-carrier-grade-nat)

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your reply my ip starts with 103

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.